# Email signature table ignoring border line and icon vertical alignment when sending from Apple Mail to Gmail

Tags: html, css, html-email

The original issue I was having has been very kindly solved and I'm now just looking to get the rest of my signature aligned nicely on the right of the corrected code in the answers. The section I need on the right is:

```
<td width="" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0px;">
  <table class="ExternalClass" width="170" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" valign="middle" style="padding-bottom: 2px; color: #000000 !important; font-size: 14px; font-family: Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:15px;">
        <b>Ben Powis</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="color: #000000 !important; font-size: 10px; font-family:Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:17px;"> Filmmaker </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="20" valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 20px; color: #000000 !important; font-size: 10px; font-family: Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:2px;line-height:10px;">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYTQs4EzP_-qXaNPzX5PYAezfZw1RQVQdsjPUhv0MclZM0ajbSrxTGKOmWtcllKm-9EZSeMevtJz3a4L8xf73f8GxZ_8=s2560" height="11" width="11" alt="" />
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #000000 !important; font-size: 10px; font-family: Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:4px;line-height:10px;">
        <style=" color: #000000 !important; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10px;">+44 20 7636 5497</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="20" valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 20px; color: #000000 !important; font-size: 10px; font-family: Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:2px;line-height:10px;">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYT47LE5Vek2JhDA684SvsOdskAKhnw4wInfHGbIyZn9EPhuvIUPgMpP6mnhbgmxGf7g4eLiB84hU4e5gxFYG9Pyfp9Pvg=s2560" height="12" width="11" alt="" />
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #000000 !important; font-size: 10px; font-family: Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:4px;line-height:10px;">
        <style=" color: #000000 !important; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10px;">+44 7904 496406</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="20" valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 20px; color: #16254D; font-size: 10px; font-family: Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:0px;line-height:10px;">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYQxt75TGE-8FDRVc_VF0nZbW51k33wlpPrVv1vxfqIma_P2wOmBFtLjZQ5viGso5__OR_drxhSe08Bc4YuKaVJa9hesxQ=s2560" height="11" width="11" alt="" />
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #000000 !important; font-size: 10px; font-family: Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:0px;line-height:10px;">
        <a>
          <style=" color: #000000 !important; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10px;">quitefranklyproductions.com</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm having an issue with my HTML email signature not recognizing a table's borderline and the social icons ignoring their vertical middle alignment. Is there any chance someone could point me at something I'm missing? It works fine when sending from Gmail and receives ok in Outlook and Apple Mail. But when I send from Apple Mail, the right sided 1px border line disappears and the social icons ignore their vertical middle alignment. I'm very new to this and employed some freelance help to get it off the ground.

```html
<table class="ExternalClass" width="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <tr>
    <td width="90" valign="middle" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 15px; border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0: border-left: 0; border-right: solid 1px #000000; text-align:center;">
      <a href="https://www.quitefranklyproductions.com/" style=" color: #0E0E57; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10px;">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYQU5Y9jpTc1U1eUbcfgE7yML1JoXGFAouIRsdobjRdwAzwB6tyzgCeWNi3j5Whx_xOYp-UROF-k77T7wKwlomjF9eqOaA=s1600" width="93" height="56" alt="" />
      </a>
      <br />
      <a href="https://twitter.com/QF_production" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;">
        <img valign="middle" width="24" height="24" style="border: none; width: px; max-width: px !important; height: 24px; max-height: 24px !important;" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYSREHe5H6_gtIHxKs22OPbHZG8PtUaa4ZgWh1VXVc44F893Go1Dh4SWXNXE-RY-VHKQaOTKPpwZzu2ed6-N14M63PofpA=s2560">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/QF_Production/" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;">
        <img valign="middle" width="24" height="24" style="border: none; width: px; max-width: px !important; height: 24px; max-height: 24px !important;" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYSP9cqVmMIPFfm6UrpOZ4LMiMLsFY_YrwU-QiqAZxIuovaFnE_q5RnB7Y8G3sYP-EcCxpvGJKpoj3J32qvNbOuO-UMT6Q=s2560">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/quite-frankly-productions/" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;">
        <img valign="middle" width="24" height="24" style="border: none; width: px; max-width: px !important; height: 24px; max-height: 24px !important;" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYQCXDiQwZzMwb7Sbh0VOrqGA22GxjZCTyRKQAIP5cfDSJWZw1ZpBYG-HQUoBWevqKmiNG0adCEvICuol48QR6THUesXQQ=s2560">
      </a>
    </td>
```

I have been trying to tweak the inline css with not much success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `<td>` instances has `border-bottom: 0:`. This should be `border-bottom: 0;`. That may fix your border issue.  In regards to vertically centered elements, you'll want to place each social media icon image in its own cell and use `<td valign="middle">`. Overall, if I were to code up your layout for email, it would look more like this...

```html
<!-- Signature -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-spacing:0 !important; border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <!-- left column -->
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="padding-right: 15px; border-right: 1px solid #000000;">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-spacing:0 !important; border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr><!-- logo -->
          <td valign="top" align="left" style="padding-bottom: 6px;">
            <a href="https://www.quitefranklyproductions.com" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYQU5Y9jpTc1U1eUbcfgE7yML1JoXGFAouIRsdobjRdwAzwB6tyzgCeWNi3j5Whx_xOYp-UROF-k77T7wKwlomjF9eqOaA=s1600" alt="Quite Frankly Productions" width="93" height="56" style="margin:0; outline:none; border:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display:block;">
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><!-- social channels -->
          <td valign="top" align="center">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-spacing:0 !important; border-collapse:collapse;">
              <tr>
                <td valign="middle">
                  <a href="https://twitter.com/QF_production" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYSREHe5H6_gtIHxKs22OPbHZG8PtUaa4ZgWh1VXVc44F893Go1Dh4SWXNXE-RY-VHKQaOTKPpwZzu2ed6-N14M63PofpA=s2560" alt="X" width="24" height="24" style="margin:0; outline:none; border:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display:block;">
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td valign="middle">
                  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/QF_Production/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYSP9cqVmMIPFfm6UrpOZ4LMiMLsFY_YrwU-QiqAZxIuovaFnE_q5RnB7Y8G3sYP-EcCxpvGJKpoj3J32qvNbOuO-UMT6Q=s2560" alt="IN" width="24" height="24" style="margin:0; outline:none; border:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display:block;">
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td valign="middle"> 
                  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/quite-frankly-productions/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYQCXDiQwZzMwb7Sbh0VOrqGA22GxjZCTyRKQAIP5cfDSJWZw1ZpBYG-HQUoBWevqKmiNG0adCEvICuol48QR6THUesXQQ=s2560" alt="LI" width="24" height="24" style="margin:0; outline:none; border:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display:block;">
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <!-- right column -->
    <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding-left: 15px;">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-spacing:0 !important; border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" valign="top" align="left" style="padding-bottom:3px; font-family: Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold; line-height: 16px; color: #000000;">
            Ben Powis
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" valign="top" align="left" style="padding-bottom:12px; font-family: Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12px; color: #000000;">
            Filmmaker
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" align="left" width="20" style="padding-bottom:3px;">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYTQs4EzP_-qXaNPzX5PYAezfZw1RQVQdsjPUhv0MclZM0ajbSrxTGKOmWtcllKm-9EZSeMevtJz3a4L8xf73f8GxZ_8=s2560" alt="*" width="11" height="11" style="margin:0; outline:none; border:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display:block;">
          </td>
          <td valign="middle" align="left" style="padding-bottom:3px; font-family: Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12px;">
            <a href="tel:+44 20 7636 5497" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank">+44 20 7636 5497</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" align="left" width="20" style="padding-bottom:3px;">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYT47LE5Vek2JhDA684SvsOdskAKhnw4wInfHGbIyZn9EPhuvIUPgMpP6mnhbgmxGf7g4eLiB84hU4e5gxFYG9Pyfp9Pvg=s2560" alt="*" width="11" height="11" style="margin:0; outline:none; border:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display:block;">
          </td>
          <td valign="middle" align="left" style="padding-bottom:3px; font-family: Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12px;">
            <a href="tel:+44 7904 496406" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank">+44 7904 496406</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" align="left" width="20" style="padding-bottom:3px;">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYQxt75TGE-8FDRVc_VF0nZbW51k33wlpPrVv1vxfqIma_P2wOmBFtLjZQ5viGso5__OR_drxhSe08Bc4YuKaVJa9hesxQ=s2560" alt="*" width="11" height="11" style="margin:0; outline:none; border:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display:block;">
          </td>
          <td valign="middle" align="left" style="padding-bottom:3px; font-family: Verdana,  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12px;">
            <a href="https://quitefranklyproductions.com" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank">quitefranklyproductions.com</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Regarding the rest of your signature (Name, title, etc.), you can insert that `<table>` in the parent `<td>` of my original HTML snippet (see comment 'left column'). I updated my HTML snippet. Note: your snippet contains a opening `<span>` and a closing `</a>` around the phone numbers. That's invalid. It's best to wrap phone numbers with an `<a href>` as shown in my example.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much Chris! This has definitely solved the border line and social icon alignment! What I didn't include (because I didn't want to post too much code) is the 2nd half of the signature which is now appearing underneath what i posted earlier when I need it appearing on the right hand side, any chance you might be able to assist? Or do I need to post a new question with the code I have underneath?

Comment: Sure. Perhaps add a new HTML snippet to your original question and state that you wish for that content to appear to the right of the existing signature content.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I've updated it with the right-hand section of the signature at the top of the question now so it's easier to see first. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I had it left aligned originally with a 15px padding on the left to match the padding between the logo and the border line on the left side, thanks so much for your help with this!

Comment: I updated my answer to address the additional signature content. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much Chris, really looking good now. There's one last thing I'm struggling with - I am looking to remove the hyperlinks from the phone numbers and website but when I remove the 'a href' and start the lines with 'style="color....' and remove the '</a>' Outlook seems to push them all up onto one line and has '</style="color:>' at the end... feel like I'm oversimplifying or missing something...

Comment: It actually seems like there is a spacing line height spacing issue going on when viewing a reply from an Outlook desktop (when sent from either Apple Mail or Gmail). It just looks like it's increasing the line height between those 3 contact lines, do you think that might be being caused by the hyperlinks?

Comment: Just an update from some testing - looks like it's not actually even showing with the increased line height on the Outlook side of things, just in the reply chain on the Gmail side of things when it comes back (looking good on the Apple Mail side of things in the reply chain). Any idea why that might be? If possible to advise on this and the removal of the 'a href' hyperlinks I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: Email clients will insert <a href> on things that it 'thinks' should be links. That includes dates, phone number and web addresses.  So to avoid this you apply and style those elements (dates, phone numbers, etc.) with <a href> as shown in the example.  You cannot avoid the fact that those elements will turn into links in many email clients so I suggest keeping them as links and style them as you wish.

Comment: Ok, gotcha makes sense! Only thing then really is that Outlook seems to be applying that line height adjustment in replies and underlining the 3 contact links, weirdly though it only displays in Gmail on the reply chain, in the receipient inbox it's displaying fine, and in Apple Mail it has the right line height and only underlined the website URL. Very strange... Outlook definitely seems like the most tricky customer of the 3 clients!

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing can be done to control how a signature renders beyond its original send.  It's common to see a signature in a chain of message lose its original formatting.  If you want a bulletproof email signature make it a text-based one. Otherwise you'll have to make peace with the fact that a HTML-based signature will take some hits once it's resent.  You can rest assure that it's not just your signature though. It happens to more complex HTML-email signatures.  It's accepted/goes unnoticed for the most part.

Comment: Totally understood, I'm seeing more and more text-only signatures cropping up on email chains these days with our clients, that must be the reason. Well I really appreciate your help Chris you've been an absolute life-saver, I've been tearing my hair out over this stuff (slow/stressful process trying to teach myself these things while doing my day job!). So thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted (check mark) if you're all set.